# One of parameters isn't sent into controller properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating RoR app. I have a problem with sending parameter from view to controller.

My view:

```
<%= form_for(:message, url: create_message_path ) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: 'Write new post' %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :user2_id, @user %>
    <%= f.submit 'Send', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

after clicking the button, controller is called with create action where I want to create new message. Message model fields are: user1_id, user2_id, content.

```
def create
    @message = Message.new(user1_id: current_user.id, user2_id: params[:user2_id], content: params[:content])
    if @message.save
      CORRECT
    else
      INCORRECT
    end
  end
```

Problem is with params[:content]. It seems as if this parameter was nil while creating new message. When I change code like this, it works:

```
@message = Message.new(user1_id: current_user.id, user2_id: params[:user2_id], content: 'hello')
```

Do you have some suggestions why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look into the `params` that are generated in the logs, `content` will be inside the `message`, so you need to change

```
@message = Message.new(user1_id: current_user.id, user2_id: params[:user2_id], content: params[:content])
```

to

```
@message = Message.new(user1_id: current_user.id, user2_id: params[:user2_id], content: params[:message][:content])
```

Comment: I will, but there is some time restriction, so I must wait :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `hidden_field_tag` you should use `hidden_field` helper:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user2_id, @user %>
```

Also, in your controller you should have:

```
def create
  @message = Message.new(message_params.merge({user1_id: current_user.id})
  # ...
end
# ...
private

def message_params
  params.require(:message).permit(:user2_id, :content)
end
```